# How to replace string from getting postman as parameter

Tags: php, string

Currently i am facing issue of replace string , I used postman & passing string in postman like `[{"id":"115","flag":"1","qty":"3","size":"10"}]` as a parameters but when i print string i am getting output like `[{\"id\":\"115\",\"flag\":\"1\",\"qty\":\"3\",\"size\":\"10\"}]`  , So i want to only remove `'\'` from string i have tried following code but not work.

```
$fliesid_in_store = $_REQUEST['fliesid_in_store'];
echo $res = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]/", "", $fliesid_in_store);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [stripslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php).

```
$fliesid_in_store = $_REQUEST['fliesid_in_store'];
echo stripslashes($fliesid_in_store);
```

Answer (score 1):

The string you mentioned is in json format

```
$json = [{"id":"115","flag":"1","qty":"3","size":"10"}] //this is json
```

Assign that to variable and decode it.

```
$string = json_decode($json,TRUE) this give result in array format
```

In your case

```
$string = json_decode($_REQUEST['fliesid_in_store'],TRUE);
```